# How can i set first day of first month of current year in datetimepicker

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I set first day of first month of current year in `DateTimePicker`.

eg. I want to show this time format in `DateTimePicker`:

```
01/01/2013
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can't you just use:

```
picker.Value = new DateTime(picker.Value.Year, 1, 1);
```

? If that *doesn't* work, please give more context.

Comment: +1 There couldn't possibly be any other interpretations of that question :)

Answer (score 0):

Set it like this

```
picker.Value = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.dateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
```